# Angular 5 remove option from select after click

Tags: arrays, angular, select

I have two arrays:

```
availableTargets: [ {id: 1, name: "Target 1"}, {id: 2, name: "Target 2"}, {id: 3, name: Target 3" ];
selectedTargets: [];
```

I create a multiple selectlist:

```
<select multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let target of availableTargets" [value]="target .id" (click)="AddTarget($event)">{{target.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

When a user clicks an option, I want to add the 'Target' to the selectedTarget array and remove it from the availableTargets array.

```
public AddTarget(event) {
    let id = event.target.id;
    this.availableTargets = this.availableTargets .filter(function (el) { return el.id != id });
    this.selectedTargets.push(event.target.id);
  }
```

My multiple select list does not update after removing an element from the availableTarget array. How do I trigger this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by simply using index

**Template side :**

```
<select multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let target of availableTargets; let i = index;" [value]="target .id" (click)="AddTarget(i)">{{target.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**Component Side :**

```
  public AddTarget(index) {
    this.selectedTargets.push(this.availableTargets[index]);
    this.availableTargets.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select)**